# infix to postfix with non-commuting operators

Tags: operators, postfix-mta, infix-notation

I have a question when it comes to - / operators in postfix vs infix.

From the assignment

> The input string 5 4 + 3 10 * + is equivalent to the infix expression
>   (5 + 4) + (3 * 10) The answer is 39.

I follow that. Then I get confused by this statement.

> We also have to worry about the non-commuting operators – and / . We
>   will evaluate the postfix string    4 5 –     as 4 – 5   and,
>   likewise, will evaluate    4 5 /    as  4 / 5 .

When I do that however...I get different results with infix vs postfix.

Modifying the first example to include subtraction.

infix

> (5 - 4) + (3 * 10) = 31

postfix

> 5 4 - 3 10 * +

29....right?

SO I'm confused. The results of infix and postfix are supposed to be the same right? Is this a typo in the actual assignment or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How'd you get 29? That would help us understand where the error comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're evaluating postfix you use a stack: you push operands and when you get to an operator you pop the required operands and push the evaluated result.

In the case of commutative operators like `+` it doesn't matter which order the operands are in. So for example:

```
5 4 +
```

can be evaluated as

```
PUSH 5
PUSH 4
PUSH (POP + POP)
```

where the first POP will yield 4 and the second POP 5. So you have really evaluated 4+5.

But in the case of non-commutative operators, this won't work. You have to evaluate 5 / 4, not 4 / 5. So you need either to use temporary variables:

```
 PUSH 5
 PUSH 4
 let d = POP; // divisor = 4
 let q = POP; // quotient = 5
 PUSH q/d;    // push the dividend
```

or else introduce a SWAP operation, which swaps the top two items on the stack:

```
PUSH 5
PUSH 4
SWAP
PUSH (POP / POP)
```

or else compile the postfix so as to push in the opposite order:

```
PUSH 4
PUSH 5
PUSH (POP/POP)
```

Comment: Thanks! This does work. The wording of the assignment confused me.  A swap or something of the sort is indeed what I need. I love this stuff. No sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

The postfix also evaluates to 31.

Let's go through this step by step: Our expression is

```
5 4 - 3 10 * +
```

So the stack progresses as follows:

```
5
5 4
1      # after evaluating -, i.e. popping 5 and 4 and pushing 5 - 4
1 3
1 3 10
1 30   # after evaluating *, i.e. popping 3 and 10 and pushing 3 * 10
31     # after evaluating +, i.e. popping 1 and 30 and pushing 1 + 30
```

Comment: The assignment handles it differently. It followed the first in, first out model when processing the stock.

Comment: I totally follow your example. You followed LIFO...I totally see how that works. 

The assignment did the opposite. It followed FIFO..and it gave me errors when doing subtraction because 5-4 in infix becomes 4-5 in postfix.

Comment: But the assignment states that `4 5 -` is to be evaluated as `4 - 5`, so `5 4 -` should be evaluated as `5 - 4`. I don't think that has anything to do with the order in which the operations are applied, it's just a matter of which operand you put on which side of the `-`.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure what the FIFO strategy to evaluate RPN is; I've only ever seen it done with a stack. Google does little to enlighten me there. >.<

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have been confused because the example is 4-5 and your example is 5-4 for the infix notation.

To evaluate the postfix 5 4 - 3 10 * +:
5 4 - = 5 - 4 = 1
3 10 * = 3 * 10 = 30
1 30 + = 1 + 30 = 31

The second statement from your assignment just clarifies that if you have something like 4 5 -, that it will be 4 - 5 and not 5 - 4.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement about - and /, it's 4 5 -. That's -1, i.e. 4-5.

In the longer expression: 5 4 - 3 10 * +

It's 5 - 4, because the 5 comes first. Thus, it *is* (5-4) + (3*10) = 31.

If it was 4 5 - 3 10 * + then that would evaluate to 29 (i.e. (4-5) + (3*10)). This doesn't have to do with prefix or postfix notation, but the order that we evaluate the arguments in, because - and / are non commutative. The assignment specifies that they will be evaluated in the "intuitive" order, i.e. that x y - means x - y.